# module.export = {} with Vite React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I created a react App with Vite, and I want to use **Apollo** extension to get Intellisense when building GraphQL queries.

According to the extension docs, I created an `apollo.config.js` file at the root with this code :

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    service: {
      name: "my-graphql-app",
      url: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
    },
  },
};
```

But since my React app is of `type : module` , eslint warns me with a "module not found". Thus Apollo extension cannot find the config file.

I tried by turning it into a ESModule, exporting it :

```
export const client=  {
    service: {
      name: "my-graphql-app",
      url: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
    },
  },
```

But although the error about not finding the config file goes away, nothing else happens.

Any hints to fix this would be much appreciated.